# Recursive MySql view: is this possible?

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, view

I have an table in my MySql database that has the following columns:

```
- id
- parent_id
- visible
```

Basically if I have a **table** populated like this:

```
    id     name      parent_id      visible
    ------ --------- -------------- -------
    1      Admin     0              1
    2      Review    0              0
    3      Archive   2              1
    4      Support   0              1
```

Though the hierarchy is...

> ```
> 1 - Admin
> 2 - Review
>    3 - Archive
> 4 - Support
> ```

I would like Archive (3) to essentially inherit the 'visible' attribute from it's parent row --  Review (2).  I'd like to return this in a **view** like this:

```
    id     name      parent_id      visible
    ------ --------- -------------- -------
    1      Admin     0              1
    2      Review    0              0
    3      Archive   2              0
    4      Support   0              1
```

Does anyone know if this is possible in MySql without resorting to a stored procedure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a normal query using a CASE statement for the visible column:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.parent_id,
       CASE WHEN a.parent_id = 0 
       then a.visible
       else b.visible
       end as visible
from myTable a
left join myTable b on a.parent_id = b.id
```

You could also create the view (same code):

```
create view myTableView as
select a.id, a.name, a.parent_id,
       CASE WHEN a.parent_id = 0 
       then a.visible
       else b.visible
       end as visible
from myTable a
left join myTable b on a.parent_id = b.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Fosco.  I was having complete brain freeze.